# JQuery/JavaScript - Add List Items to Array based on Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to add the items in the list below into a string or array. In order to get the right table, I need to get the items based on the class. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="height: 125px;" class="testClass1">
   <ul>
      <li>dsokoloff 1 submitted for approval  on 04/25/2011</li>
      <li>dsokoloff 2 submitted for approval  on 04/25/2011</li>
      <li>dsokoloff 3 submitted for approval  on 04/25/2011</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking. I don't know what _"get the items based on class"_ means. Do you want multiple arrays of (something?) indexed by the CSS class on some parent element? Are you trying to all HTML elements with a particular class? Given the HTML sample you have provided, what do you want the output to be?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking here...

Comment: **More information => better answers.**

Comment: My guess is that `approval` is a class for you?

Answer (score 4):

With the question being so unclear, I can only guess.  If you want the `li` contents in an array, simply iterate over each and push them onto the array:

```
$(function() {
    var myArray = [];

    $('.testClass1 li').each( function() {
         myArray.push($(this).text());   
    });

    alert(myArray);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yFFnf/